# making submenu appear vertically under topmenu

Tags: html, css

Im trying to figure out how to get the submenu to display vertically under top menu  when im using a mobile phone that will give click results on the top menu button to expand the submenu below the test2 LI .

Im sure its display or something simple to do with the LI or UL but im having trouble figuring it out and its hard on this website to have a working example heres a good working fiddle just shrink frame below 767px 
 only using .btmenu and the li  https://jsfiddle.net/1t2fhdb9/20/

```css
@media all and (min-width: 767px) {












/* MOBILE BROWSER THING*/
.menu{
width:60%;
}  
a.menu-link {
display:none;
}
#mobmenu_hidden{
display:none;
}
header{
margin:0 auto;border: px solid purple;
width:80%;
display:table;
}
#logohold{
text-decoration: none;
width:30%;
border:px solid purple;
max-width:223px;
height:60px;
float:left;
margin-top:4px;
}
#logohold img{
text-decoration: none;
width:100%;
border:px solid purple;
max-width:223px;
height:60px;


}
#logohold a{
text-decoration: none;
}
#navhold{
margin:0 auto;
border: px dotted black;
width:80%;
display:table;

}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}


body {
min-height:100px; /* This should be equal to the height of your header */
}



#fixednav{
background-color:#00AFEA !important;
border: px solid green;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
z-index:5;
box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 0px BLACK;
}
.main {
border: px solid red;
z-index:2;width: 100%;

}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky + .main {
  padding-top: 102px;
}





#navtop{
float:right;
line-height:60px;
border: px solid blue;
width:85%;
height:60px;
background-color:#00AFEA !important;
}
span.telem{
background:url('')  no-repeat no-repeat ;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0.0em;
background-size: 26px 26px;
padding-left: 30px;
}
span .telem a{
height:100%;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:red;
font-size:15px;
}



#tpmenu3{border: px solid yellow;

text-transform: uppercase;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
height:100%;
width:60%;
margin:0 auto;
}
#tpmenu3 li {margin:0 auto;border: px solid red;

height:100%;
}
.hr{margin:0 auto;width:160px;text-align:left;margin-left:-5px;}
.active{
background-color:#000 !important;
color:#FFF!important; 
}
#tpmenu3 li a {color:#0094c8;border: px solid yellow;
padding-left:5%;
padding-right:5%;
text-align: center;
font-size:12px;
white-space: nowrap ;
text-decoration: none;
}


#btmenu1{
border: px solid yellow;

margin: auto;
z-index:;
width:100%;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:30px;
text-align:right;
float:right;
}
ul#btmenu1 > li{ 
padding:0;
margin:0;
display: inline;
}
#btmenu1 li > a{
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
margin-left:1%;
margin-right:1%;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:;
font-size:11px;
color:#FFF;
padding-left:1%;
padding-right:1%;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#btmenu1 > li > a:hover{
background-color:#333;
color:#FFF; 
}

#phoneno{
text-decoration:none; 
float:right;
}
/*     SUB MENU     */
#btmenu1 > li:hover .sub_menu{z-index:5;
position:absolute;
vertical-align: middle;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
background-color:#666;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:table;
padding-right:3px;
border:#333 solid 2px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

li.top_quote {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;

}
ul.submenu {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
.top_quote:hover > ul.submenu {
    display:block;
}

.headleft{border: px solid green; }

#navbot{
  width:100%;
  border: px solid green;
}











#navagation{
  width:100%;
  border: px solid red;
}
.btmenu {
display: flex;
justify-content:space-between; 
list-style: none;
border:px solid green;
}
ul.btmenu > li{
border: px solid yellow; 
list-spadding:15px;
style-type: none;
padding:8px;
}
.btmenu li > a{border:px solid red;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
  font-size: 1.0vw;
padding:8px;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
white-space: nowrap;


}
#btmenu:hover > ul.submenu {
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;/*no need for height or width*/
vertical-align: middle;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
background-color:;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:table;

border:#333 solid 2px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.btmenu > li > a:hover{/*backgorund color on hover*/
background-color:#333;
color:#FFF; 


}




/*     SUB MENU     */
.submenu{z-index:5;
background-color: #00AFEA !important;/*not shown unless hover*/
border:#333 solid 1px;
display:none;
padding:5px 5px 0 0;
}
.btmenu > li:hover .submenu{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color:#FFF; 
list-style-type: none;
}
.submenu li{ border: px solid green;
margin: 0;
padding:0;  
width:100%;
float:left;
display:block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.submenu li a{  border: px solid pink;margin: 0;
padding: 15px;  
position: relative;
display:block;
vertical-align: middle;
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
}
.submenu > li > a:hover{/*backgorund color on hover*/
background-color: #FFF;
}

}
@media all and (max-width: 766px) {
     /* start of tablet styles */


/*      FOOTER      */



.goog-logo-link {
   display:none !important;
} 

.goog-te-gadget{
   color: transparent !important;
}

    .translation-links {

 }
 .translation-links img {
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity: 1.0;
    opacity: 1.0;
    border:0;
    cursor: pointer;
    
    height:24px;
    width:24px;
    }
.translation-links img:hover {
    filter:alpha(opacity=30);
    -moz-opacity: 0.30;
    opacity: 0.30;
    }


/* CSS Document */
html,body{
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color:#000;
}


/* unvisited link */
a:link {
  color:#000;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  color:#000;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  color:#000;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  color:#000;
}


a, img {
border:none;
outline:none;
}
/* CSS Document */
html,body{
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
height:100%;
width:100%;

}
/* MOBILE BROWSER THING*/
.menu{
width:60%;
}  
a.menu-link {
display:none;
}
header{
margin:0 auto;border: px solid purple;
width:100%;
display:table;
}
#logohold{

}
#logohold img{
text-decoration: none;
width:35%;
margin-top:5px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
border: px solid green;
max-width:220px;
height:100%;
float:left;
}
#logohold a{
text-decoration: none;
}
#mobmenu_hidden{
display: inline-block;border: 1px dotted black;
float:right;
margin-right:10px;
padding:5px;

position: relative;
top: 45%;
transform: perspective(1px) translateY(45%);
cursor: pointer;
}


#navhold{
margin:0 auto;
border: px dotted black;
width:100%;
display:table;

}




/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}


body {
min-height:100px; /* This should be equal to the height of your header */
}



#fixednav{
background-color:#00AFEA !important;
border: px solid green;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
z-index:5;
box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 0px BLACK;
}
.main {
border: px solid red;
z-index:2;width: 100%;

}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky + .main {
  padding-top: 102px;
}





#navtop{
float:right;
line-height:60px;
border: px solid blue;
width:85%;
height:60px;
background-color:#00AFEA !important;
}
span.telem{
background:url('')  no-repeat no-repeat ;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0.0em;
background-size: 26px 26px;
padding-left: 30px;
}
span .telem a{
height:100%;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:red;
font-size:15px;
}



#tpmenu3{border: px solid yellow;

text-transform: uppercase;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
height:100%;
width:60%;
margin:0 auto;
}
#tpmenu3 li {margin:0 auto;border: px solid red;

height:100%;
}
.hr{margin:0 auto;width:160px;text-align:left;margin-left:-5px;}
.active{
background-color:#000 !important;
color:#FFF!important; 
}
#tpmenu3 li a {color:#0094c8;border: px solid yellow;
padding-left:5%;
padding-right:5%;
text-align: center;
font-size:12px;
white-space: nowrap ;
text-decoration: none;
}




#btmenu1{
width:99%;
border: px solid yellow;
margin: auto;
z-index:;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
display:table;
}
ul#btmenu1 > li{
float: right;
border: px solid green;
width:48%;
text-align:center;
padding:0;
margin:0;

}
#btmenu1 li > a{
width:98%;
border: px solid red;
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:11px;
color:#FFF;
display:block;
text-transform:uppercase;

}
#btmenu1 > li > a:hover{
background-color:#333;
color:#FFF; 
}

#phoneno{
text-decoration:none; 
float:right;
}
/*     SUB MENU     */
#btmenu1 > li:hover .sub_menu{
z-index:5;
position:absolute;
vertical-align: middle;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
background-color:#666;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:table;
padding-right:3px;
border:#333 solid 2px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

li.top_quote {
    position:relative;
 

}
ul.submenu {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
.top_quote:hover > ul.submenu {
    display:block;
}

.headleft{border: px solid green; }














#navbot{
  width:100%;
  border: px solid green;
}
#navagation{
  width:100%;
  border: px solid red;
}
#navagation{
display:none;
float:right;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#btmenu{
display:table;
z-index:1;
position:relative;
width:100%;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
}
ul#btmenu > li{ 
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#btmenu li > a{ 
height:50px;
width:96%;
line-height:50px;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
color:#000;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color:#666;
border:#333 solid 2px;
border-radius: 4px;
margin:3px;
}
#btmenu > li > a:hover{
background-color:#333;
color:#FFF; 
}
/*     SUB MENU     */
.sub_menu{
display:none;
}

#top_menu_phonem{
height:100%;
line-height:350%;
text-decoration:none;
float:right;
clear:right;
margin-right:2%;
}
#top_menu_phonem a{ 
height:100%;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:red;
font-size:13px;
}
span.telem{
background:url('../images/icon_phone.png')  no-repeat no-repeat ;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0.0em;
background-size: 26px 26px;
padding-left: 25px;
}
span .telem a{
height:100%;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:red;
font-size:15px;
}
#top_menu_phone{
display:none;
}

}


@media all and (min-width: 767px) {
/*left*/    
.hidden { display: none; }   

.zipform{margin-bottom:18px;}
.container {
  width:100%;
  border: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
}


}     
     /* start of tablet styles */
@media all and (max-width: 766px) {
    
    
 
.hidden { display: none; }   


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="canonical" href="" />
<title>test</title>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style3.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index3.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<script src="scripts/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#mobmenu_hidden").click(function(){
$("#navagation").toggle();
});
});
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#blah').removeClass('hidden');
 });

</script>



</head>
<body>

<div id="fixednav">



<!----------------------------------------------------------------HEADER---------------------------------------------------------------->
<header>
<div id="navhold">
    <div id="logohold"><a href="index.php"><img src="logo"  alt="logo" /></a></div><!--headleft-->
<div id="mobmenu_hidden">MENU</div><!--mobmenu_hidden-->
<div id="navbot">
<div id="navagation">
<ul class="btmenu">
<li class="top_quote"><a href="QuoteLanding.php">test1</a></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="QuoteLanding.php">top menu</a>
<ul class="submenu">
<li class="subitem"><a href="Auto.php">submenu1</a></li>
<li class="subitem"><a href="SR-22.php">submenu</a></li>
<li class="subitem"><a href="Life.php">submenu</a></li>
<li class="subitem"><a href="Home.php">submenu</a></li>
<li class="subitem"><a href="Renters.php">submenu</a></li>
<li class="subitem"><a href="Business.php">submenu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="Learning.php">test2</a> </li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="index.php#WhySolid">test3</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--navagation-->

</div><!--navbot-->
</div><!--navhold-->

</header><!--header-->
</div><!--fixed nav-->

<div class="main">


<!----------------------------------------------------------------/FOOTER---------------------------------------------------------------->


  <script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = fixednav.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    fixednav.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    fixednav.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>



    <script>

$(".learn").click(function() {

  $learn = $(this);
  //getting the next element
  $content = $learn.closest(".wrap1").next().find(".content");
  $test = $learn.closest(".test").next().find(".test");
  
  //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
  $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    $learn.text(function() {
      //change text based on condition
       return $content.is(":visible") ? "Learn less!" : "Learn More!";
    });
  });

});

</script>

</div><!--main--> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I haven't checked your problem yet but I see that you opened your `<html>` tag in the `<head>` tag. You should put it before the `<head>`.

Comment: I was trying to edit out as much code as I could so people would not complain about the amount of code

Answer (score 0):

You mean open the submenu on topmenu li hover and show it between the topmenu li and test2 li? if yes this just remove position: absolute from the submenu class style.

```css
@media all and (min-width: 767px) {

/* MOBILE BROWSER THING*/
.menu{
width:60%;
}  
a.menu-link {
display:none;
}
#mobmenu_hidden{
display:none;
}
header{
margin:0 auto;border: px solid purple;
width:80%;
display:table;
}
#logohold{
text-decoration: none;
width:30%;
border:px solid purple;
max-width:223px;
height:60px;
float:left;
margin-top:4px;
}
#logohold img{
text-decoration: none;
width:100%;
border:px solid purple;
max-width:223px;
height:60px;


}
#logohold a{
text-decoration: none;
}
#navhold{
margin:0 auto;
border: px dotted black;
width:80%;
display:table;

}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}


body {
min-height:100px; /* This should be equal to the height of your header */
}



#fixednav{
background-color:#00AFEA !important;
border: px solid green;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
z-index:5;
box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 0px BLACK;
}
.main {
border: px solid red;
z-index:2;width: 100%;

}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky + .main {
  padding-top: 102px;
}





#navtop{
float:right;
line-height:60px;
border: px solid blue;
width:85%;
height:60px;
background-color:#00AFEA !important;
}
span.telem{
background:url('')  no-repeat no-repeat ;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0.0em;
background-size: 26px 26px;
padding-left: 30px;
}
span .telem a{
height:100%;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:red;
font-size:15px;
}



#tpmenu3{border: px solid yellow;

text-transform: uppercase;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
height:100%;
width:60%;
margin:0 auto;
}
#tpmenu3 li {margin:0 auto;border: px solid red;

height:100%;
}
.hr{margin:0 auto;width:160px;text-align:left;margin-left:-5px;}
.active{
background-color:#000 !important;
color:#FFF!important; 
}
#tpmenu3 li a {color:#0094c8;border: px solid yellow;
padding-left:5%;
padding-right:5%;
text-align: center;
font-size:12px;
white-space: nowrap ;
text-decoration: none;
}


#btmenu1{
border: px solid yellow;

margin: auto;
z-index:;
width:100%;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:30px;
text-align:right;
float:right;
}
ul#btmenu1 > li{ 
padding:0;
margin:0;
display: inline;
}
#btmenu1 li > a{
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
margin-left:1%;
margin-right:1%;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:;
font-size:11px;
color:#FFF;
padding-left:1%;
padding-right:1%;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#btmenu1 > li > a:hover{
background-color:#333;
color:#FFF; 
}

#phoneno{
text-decoration:none; 
float:right;
}
/*     SUB MENU     */
#btmenu1 > li:hover .sub_menu{z-index:5;
position:absolute;
vertical-align: middle;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
background-color:#666;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:table;
padding-right:3px;
border:#333 solid 2px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

li.top_quote {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;

}
ul.submenu {
  display:none;
}
.top_quote:hover > ul.submenu {
    display:block;
}

.headleft{border: px solid green; }

#navbot{
  width:100%;
  border: px solid green;
}











#navagation{
  width:100%;
  border: px solid red;
}
.btmenu {
display: flex;
justify-content:space-between; 
list-style: none;
border:px solid green;
}
ul.btmenu > li{
border: px solid yellow; 
list-spadding:15px;
style-type: none;
padding:8px;
}
.btmenu li > a{border:px solid red;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
  font-size: 1.0vw;
padding:8px;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
white-space: nowrap;


}
#btmenu:hover > ul.submenu {
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;/*no need for height or width*/
vertical-align: middle;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
background-color:;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:table;

border:#333 solid 2px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.btmenu > li > a:hover{/*backgorund color on hover*/
background-color:#333;
color:#FFF; 


}




/*     SUB MENU     */
.submenu{z-index:5;
background-color: #00AFEA !important;/*not shown unless hover*/
border:#333 solid 1px;
padding:5px 5px 0 0;
}
.btmenu > li:hover .submenu{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color:#FFF; 
list-style-type: none;
}
.submenu li{ border: px solid green;
margin: 0;
padding:0;  
width:100%;
float:left;
display:block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.submenu li a{  border: px solid pink;margin: 0;
padding: 15px;  
position: relative;
display:block;
vertical-align: middle;
text-decoration:none;
color:#000;
}
.submenu > li > a:hover{/*backgorund color on hover*/
background-color: #FFF;
}

}
@media all and (max-width: 766px) {
     /* start of tablet styles */


/*      FOOTER      */



.goog-logo-link {
   display:none !important;
} 

.goog-te-gadget{
   color: transparent !important;
}

    .translation-links {

 }
 .translation-links img {
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity: 1.0;
    opacity: 1.0;
    border:0;
    cursor: pointer;
    
    height:24px;
    width:24px;
    }
.translation-links img:hover {
    filter:alpha(opacity=30);
    -moz-opacity: 0.30;
    opacity: 0.30;
    }


/* CSS Document */
html,body{
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color:#000;
}


/* unvisited link */
a:link {
  color:#000;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  color:#000;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  color:#000;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  color:#000;
}


a, img {
border:none;
outline:none;
}
/* CSS Document */
html,body{
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
height:100%;
width:100%;

}
/* MOBILE BROWSER THING*/
.menu{
width:60%;
}  
a.menu-link {
display:none;
}
header{
margin:0 auto;border: px solid purple;
width:100%;
display:table;
}
#logohold{

}
#logohold img{
text-decoration: none;
width:35%;
margin-top:5px;
margin-left:5px;
margin-bottom:5px;
border: px solid green;
max-width:220px;
height:100%;
float:left;
}
#logohold a{
text-decoration: none;
}
#mobmenu_hidden{
display: inline-block;border: 1px dotted black;
float:right;
margin-right:10px;
padding:5px;

position: relative;
top: 45%;
transform: perspective(1px) translateY(45%);
cursor: pointer;
}


#navhold{
margin:0 auto;
border: px dotted black;
width:100%;
display:table;

}




/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}


body {
min-height:100px; /* This should be equal to the height of your header */
}



#fixednav{
background-color:#00AFEA !important;
border: px solid green;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
z-index:5;
box-shadow: 0px 1.5px 0px BLACK;
}
.main {
border: px solid red;
z-index:2;width: 100%;

}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.sticky + .main {
  padding-top: 102px;
}





#navtop{
float:right;
line-height:60px;
border: px solid blue;
width:85%;
height:60px;
background-color:#00AFEA !important;
}
span.telem{
background:url('')  no-repeat no-repeat ;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0.0em;
background-size: 26px 26px;
padding-left: 30px;
}
span .telem a{
height:100%;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:red;
font-size:15px;
}



#tpmenu3{border: px solid yellow;

text-transform: uppercase;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
height:100%;
width:60%;
margin:0 auto;
}
#tpmenu3 li {margin:0 auto;border: px solid red;

height:100%;
}
.hr{margin:0 auto;width:160px;text-align:left;margin-left:-5px;}
.active{
background-color:#000 !important;
color:#FFF!important; 
}
#tpmenu3 li a {color:#0094c8;border: px solid yellow;
padding-left:5%;
padding-right:5%;
text-align: center;
font-size:12px;
white-space: nowrap ;
text-decoration: none;
}




#btmenu1{
width:99%;
border: px solid yellow;
margin: auto;
z-index:;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
display:table;
}
ul#btmenu1 > li{
float: right;
border: px solid green;
width:48%;
text-align:center;
padding:0;
margin:0;

}
#btmenu1 li > a{
width:98%;
border: px solid red;
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:11px;
color:#FFF;
display:block;
text-transform:uppercase;

}
#btmenu1 > li > a:hover{
background-color:#333;
color:#FFF; 
}

#phoneno{
text-decoration:none; 
float:right;
}
/*     SUB MENU     */
#btmenu1 > li:hover .sub_menu{
z-index:5;
position:absolute;
vertical-align: middle;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
background-color:#666;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:table;
padding-right:3px;
border:#333 solid 2px;
border-radius: 4px;
}

li.top_quote {
    position:relative;
 

}
ul.submenu {
  display:none;
}
.top_quote:hover > ul.submenu {
    display:block;
}

.headleft{border: px solid green; }

#navbot{
  width:100%;
  border: px solid green;
}
#navagation{
  width:100%;
  border: px solid red;
}
#navagation{
display:none;
float:right;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#btmenu{
display:table;
z-index:1;
position:relative;
width:100%;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
}
ul#btmenu > li{ 
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#btmenu li > a{ 
height:50px;
width:96%;
line-height:50px;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
color:#000;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color:#666;
border:#333 solid 2px;
border-radius: 4px;
margin:3px;
}
#btmenu > li > a:hover{
background-color:#333;
color:#FFF; 
}
/*     SUB MENU     */
.sub_menu{
display:none;
}

#top_menu_phonem{
height:100%;
line-height:350%;
text-decoration:none;
float:right;
clear:right;
margin-right:2%;
}
#top_menu_phonem a{ 
height:100%;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:red;
font-size:13px;
}
span.telem{
background:url('../images/icon_phone.png')  no-repeat no-repeat ;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0.0em;
background-size: 26px 26px;
padding-left: 25px;
}
span .telem a{
height:100%;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:red;
font-size:15px;
}
#top_menu_phone{
display:none;
}

}


@media all and (min-width: 767px) {
/*left*/    
.hidden { display: none; }   

.zipform{margin-bottom:18px;}
.container {
  width:100%;
  border: 2px solid #d3d3d3;
}


}     
     /* start of tablet styles */
@media all and (max-width: 766px) {
    
    
 
.hidden { display: none; }   


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="canonical" href="" />
<title>test</title>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style3.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index3.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<script src="scripts/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#mobmenu_hidden").click(function(){
$("#navagation").toggle();
});
});
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#blah').removeClass('hidden');
 });

</script>



</head>
<body>

<div id="fixednav">



<!----------------------------------------------------------------HEADER---------------------------------------------------------------->
<header>
<div id="navhold">
    <div id="logohold"><a href="index.php"><img src="logo"  alt="logo" /></a></div><!--headleft-->
<div id="mobmenu_hidden">MENU</div><!--mobmenu_hidden-->
<div id="navbot">
<div id="navagation">
<ul class="btmenu">
<li class="top_quote"><a href="QuoteLanding.php">test1</a></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="QuoteLanding.php">top menu</a>
<ul class="submenu">
<li class="subitem"><a href="Auto.php">submenu1</a></li>
<li class="subitem"><a href="SR-22.php">submenu</a></li>
<li class="subitem"><a href="Life.php">submenu</a></li>
<li class="subitem"><a href="Home.php">submenu</a></li>
<li class="subitem"><a href="Renters.php">submenu</a></li>
<li class="subitem"><a href="Business.php">submenu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="Learning.php">test2</a> </li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="index.php#WhySolid">test3</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--navagation-->

</div><!--navbot-->
</div><!--navhold-->

</header><!--header-->
</div><!--fixed nav-->

<div class="main">


<!----------------------------------------------------------------/FOOTER---------------------------------------------------------------->


  <script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = fixednav.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    fixednav.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    fixednav.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>



    <script>

$(".learn").click(function() {

  $learn = $(this);
  //getting the next element
  $content = $learn.closest(".wrap1").next().find(".content");
  $test = $learn.closest(".test").next().find(".test");
  
  //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
  $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    $learn.text(function() {
      //change text based on condition
       return $content.is(":visible") ? "Learn less!" : "Learn More!";
    });
  });

});

</script>

</div><!--main--> 
</body>
</html>
```

You can also test it here .. https://jsfiddle.net/1t2fhdb9/24/

Thanks